# Signing swift app with Enterpise provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

If I run the app via Xcode 6, using the development profile, everything is fine.
But if I deploy the app via Enterprise profile, it crashes on start.

Logs from the device say the following:

> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Did anyone encounter the same problem?

Comment: Same here, any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem here. The solution that finally worked for me was to

1. Revoke the certificate.
2. Generate a new certificate.
3. Generate a new distribution profile.

See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27326230/1344293.

**Note**: If you have apps in production which are signed with your "old" certificate and you revoke that one, those apps will eventually not work anymore. So I suggest you only revoke the certificate if you have "control" over the installed apps and you can easily redeploy your apps with the new certificate/provisioning profile.

Comment: Isn't revoking the certificate problematic for apps that are out there, signed with the old certificate?

Comment: Can you imagine this solution when you have already deployed over 300 app to 300 clients and they together have 1400 devices? It would wreak havoc if they would try to instal new builds with a a changed profile and a new certificate. The point I am making is revoking must be considered from business perspective and it applies also for OP.

Comment: Maybe the old certificate can stay in parallel for a limited time, or until it expires by itself. Problem is that only 2 enterprise distribution certificates can exist in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using frameworks that contain Swift code in your project? By default embedded content isn't expected to contain Swift. Change this in Build Settings:

[image]