# Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib; The Return of the Embedded Frameworks Bug?

Tags: ios, swift

Added a Swift UI control to my Objective-C iOS app (and therefore an embedded framework) and the app crashes on launch, presenting the "... Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib ..." message in the debugger output. Sometimes it crashes the project-instance of Xcode as well, bringing me to the "Devices" Organizer view.

This issue was supposedly resolved (with no acknowledgement from Apple) around 04 Oct 2014, but I am experiencing it with the 6.1 release of Xcode on Yosemite, building/debugging a universal iOS 8.1 app.

One individual on the Apple Developer Forum reported that the bug had returned (22 Oct 2014), and then retracted their assertion two days later (saying the issue was elsewhere); I am currently investigating that thread for a possible answer.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution on this? I am experiencing the same issue and it is extremely frustrating. Only happing in iOS 8.1 for me.

Comment: @cozmokramer8 - It seems to be the Xcode that is fragile; debug runs from within an IB view (such as XIB or Storyboard) crashes Xcode every time for me now, so I switch to a .m or .h file before building/running. It still crashes sometimes when I do that but just enough to annoy me.

Comment: I have posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800375/xcode-project-forcibly-closes-when-a-debug-session-is-started) about the Xcode project closing on debug session start.

Comment: This related question provides many answers: [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib/26949219#26949219)