# Xcode Project Forcibly Closes when a Debug Session is started

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, session

Pressing the [image] (Right Arrow) button, to begin a debug session, closes my project window rather than starting a session.

For some reason, hovering over the lower-right corner of the button, and pressing there, starts a debug session without forcibly closing my project window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Xcode bug people know about already. It happens when you run Xcode in full screen mode. The X (close button) actually sits above the run button but invisibly. The easy fix for now is just to run it windowed and not in full screen.

Comment: Thanks, @dare; I run Xcode full-screen because I have a very small screen (MacBook Air). I will keep using my own work-around of clicking the lower-right corner, which, as I now realize (thanks to your answer), is outside of the clickable area of the invisible Close button and therefore safe.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the answer provided by [Dare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3117251/dare), the Close button is invisible and occupies the same space as the Start button when Xcode is in full-screen mode, as shown in this overlay image:

[image]

Clicking the upper and lower corners, on the right side of the button, will miss the invisible Close button and prevent your project from being forcibly closed.