# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib. Issue persist

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I know that this question have been answered several times, but I have not been able to find a proper solution to this error when I am coding a Swift application for IOS 8.1:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/LONGSERIALNUMBER/AppName.app/AppName
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/LONGSERIALNUMBER/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x008A1000, size=0x001A4000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/LONGSERIALNUMBER/APPLICATION_NAME/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib

As it said in this question

[dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

I have tried all these actions:

- Restarting Xcode, iPhone, computer
- Cleaning & rebuilding
- Revoking and creating new certificate/provision profile
- Runpath Search Paths is '$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks'
- Embedded Content Contains Swift Code is 'Yes'
- Code Signing Identity is developer

but I have always got the same error...

I am using XCode 6.1 and OS X Mavericks 10.9.5 and I have an iPhone 4s for testing.

This evening I deployed my application in a friend's computer and everything was perfect. The point is that the OS X of my friend is Yosemite 10.10. So it seems that using Yosemite the problem disappears.

Any ideas will be appreciate. Thanks.

PS: for some complicated reasons I cannot update my operating system to Yosemite

Comment: I started experiencing the same issue after updating Xcode and iPhone to 8.4

Comment: The "Revoke / create new cert + provisioning profile" part is is what fixed it for me. Maybe the provisioning profiles are being cached - Did you try deleting the derived data folders from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles` ?

Comment: The solution to the problem is found in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib) - this worked for me : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41401399/559760

Answer (score 0):

Do you use cocoapods. There is a similar issue with using that. If so, try use a different version of cocoa pods.