# Importing MapKit causes Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib and could not inspect application package

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

My environment is:

> Language: Swift
>
> XCode:    6.1(the latest)
>
> iOS:      8.1.1(the latest)
>
> iPhone:   6 Plus
>
> Apple Dev Program:  Enterprise

I added MapKit to my project:

[image]

However, when archive the project and try to deploy to my iPhone 6 Plus, the app crashes. The log shows:

> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D1C5A819-0D83-429B-BE32-606E34C1333F/ChiSha.app/ChiSha
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D1C5A819-0D83-429B-BE32-606E34C1333F/ChiSha.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x1000E4000, size=0x0018C000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D1C5A819-0D83-429B-BE32-606E34C1333F/ChiSha.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
>   Dyld Version: 353.6
>
> Binary Images: 0x1200cc000 - 0x1200f3fff dyld arm64 
>   <36eff49275c23d2d815e48af33eea471> /usr/lib/dyld 0x1836d4000 -
>   0x183a30fff CoreFoundation arm64  <83a9627362333366a8543e8c2d28166e>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   0x183a34000 - 0x183b96fff CoreGraphics arm64 
>   <783a6b9356ed3b41beba516b483affb1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
>   0x183f40000 - 0x183f9dfff CoreLocation arm64 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
>   0x1845d8000 - 0x18482cfff Foundation arm64 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation 0x18584c000
>   - 0x185960fff MapKit arm64  <6d62056699ed3d94ba264fa1f388d82d> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit 0x1860ec000 -
>   0x186198fff MobileCoreServices arm64 
>   <19505cbb66af328785e293c3b2810b00>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
>   0x187d0c000 - 0x187d5efff Security arm64 
>   <823c0a3088543396bef1e351da74c835>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security 0x187f24000 -
>   0x187f97fff SystemConfiguration arm64 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
>   0x187f9c000 - 0x188910fff UIKit arm64 
>   <31ac3f3fa5153620907fbfbfd1d671b0>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit 0x19343c000 -
>   0x19343dfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64 
>    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>   0x193f4c000 - 0x194148fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64 
>    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

I believe the key here is:

> **Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib**

and

> **Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:**

Then according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104975/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib-image-not-found), I added the Mapkit.framework to the **General > Embedded Binaries**:

[image]

However, there is an error saying:

> error: strip
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip
>   exited with 1

I solved this by setting **Building Setting > Strip Debug Symbols During Copy > Release** to NO.

Then I can successfully achieve the project and export it as an Enterprise app.

However, I cannot even install the app now. If I run the app in debug mode, it shows:

[image]

I checked the log of my iPhone, and find the error saying:

> **Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path**
>   /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.sdVgX8/extracted/ChiSha.app/Frameworks/**MapKit.framework**

It seems trying to load Info.plist from Mapkit.framework but failed.

Now I am totally confused, and have no idea what I should do.

Could anyone help?

---

Update:

I also included AFNetworking and TWMessageBarMessage through Pod.

---

Update 2:

I created a complete new project, and included the MapKit. The same error occurs, i.e. after achieving and exporting and installing the ipa, the app crashed with the error: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984504/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib-issue-persist/31452538#31452538