# iOS/Xcode all projects loading a custom embedded framework started crashing today

Tags: ios, xcode7, ios9.2

I'm working on an iOS project with a moderately complex build system that creates a framework/universal binary.

While making some changes to that framework & it's test app, running it suddenly started crashing in dyld before hitting main(). It appears to be an issue with Xcode, as reverting the build and even downloading a known good version now produce the same result! Dyld is failing to load the custom framework:

```
Process:             TestApp [530]
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/Test.framework/Spin
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A7C50D3-F3A1-4DB6-8929-52607F8605A2/TestApp.app/TestApp
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A7C50D3-F3A1-4DB6-8929-52607F8605A2/TestApp.app/Frameworks/Test.framework/Test
mmap() errno=1 validating first page of
 '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A7C50D3-F3A1-4DB6-8929-52607F8605A2/TestApp.app/Frameworks/Test.framework/Test'

Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

This problem appears to have numerous possible root causes. I've tried the various solutions posted for question 32730312 (here: [Reason: no suitable image found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found)) including:

- deleting the projects Build and DerivedData folder
- deleting various Xcode cache folders
- restarting xcode, the computer & even the devices
- regenerating the provisioning profile
- discarding the project and building from a fresh pull or even previous releases of the SDK

None of those remedied the problem.

The project runs fine on the simulator, but not on a device. I'm unsure what else to try short of reinstalling Xcode and/or creating a separate user account as there's apparently something else blown apart in Xcode that I've missed!

Comment: Something may have happened with code signing identity check your certificates and provisioning profiles .

Comment: Unfortunately I had already tried that, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Update: problem solved, root cause unknown.

I tried creating a new user account, checked out code from there, and got the same error. So, it wasn't a "hidden cache" of Xcode badness either...

Left with literally nothing else to try, I uninstalled & reinstalled Xcode, and everything started working again.

I post my results here hoping the last six hours of pain can help at least a single troubled soul... Ack!