# Run application on device get this error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7

In simulator it's ok but when I try to run on real device I get this error.
I have updated the latest version of Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002).

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ActionSheetPicker_3_0.framework/ActionSheetPicker_3_0
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7C8E2E1A-FC10-4E8A-BEEF-CBCB0C42499F/mobile Banking1.app/mobile Banking1
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:`

Comment: Can you check this link might be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found

Comment: Thank you,I tried but nothing help me.