# HTMLKit running on simulator but not on device

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am using HTMLKit as a pod, it's working on simulator but not on device. Here is log of crash while trying to run on iPhone :

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/HTMLKit.framework/HTMLKit
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/224DD69B-25A6-4D52-85F7-242C9B070BE0/QT.app/QT
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/224DD69B-25A6-4D52-85F7-242C9B070BE0/QT.app/Frameworks/HTMLKit.framework/HTMLKit: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/224DD69B-25A6-4D52-85F7-242C9B070BE0/QT.app/Frameworks/HTMLKit.framework/HTMLKit'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/224DD69B-25A6-4D52-85F7-242C9B070BE0/QT.app/Frameworks/HTMLKit.framework/HTMLKit: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/224DD69B-25A6-4D52-85F7-242C9B070BE0/QT.app/Frameworks/HTMLKit.framework/HTMLKit'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/224DD69B-25A6-4D52-85F7-242C9B070BE0/QT.app/Frameworks/HTMLKit.framework/HTMLKit: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/224DD69B-25A6-4D52-85F7-242C9B070BE0/QT.app/Frameworks/HTMLKit.framework/HTMLKit'
```

Comment: I too got this error, when I was using the free Apple Developer account and try to deploy the app on the device. Changed it to the premium team in Signing Xcode, solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

Goto https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ and download "Worldwide Developer Relations - G2 Certificate" under "Apple Intermediate Certificates"
Install the certicate
Clean, Build and run.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39262254/305135