# Unable to Run Application on Device “dyld: Library not loaded”

Tags: ios, xcode9

The Xcode 9.2 I was unable to run my application on my device, I can  run it only on simulator and this the same for all my project ( Objective - C / Swift )
Some of my project runs with cocoapods and some without but also not running on Devices.

I tried everything .

```
•   Deleted All Xcode Verisons
•   Cleared Cache
•   Cleared DerivedData
•   Restarted my laptop
•   Update OS
•   Installed a fresh version of Xcode 9.2 from the app store
•   Delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
•   Delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
•   Delete ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
•   Delete ~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
•   rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
•   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
•   rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

•   Reinstalling the WWDR Certificate
•   Verified that the path has: @executable_path/Frameworks
•   Test with Bitcode: YES and NO
•   Put in "Always Trust" mode the apple certs.
•   opened my project and run on device still getting the following error  :

1.  dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
2.    Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92037D1-A936-4070-9E61-BF5DB00780D7/ProblemApp.app/ProblemApp
3.    Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
4.  /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92037D1-A936-4070-9E61-BF5DB00780D7/ProblemApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92037D1-A936-4070-9E61-BF5DB00780D7/ProblemApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
```

I have almost spend one week please help me.

Thanks!

Shiv Sharma

Comment: is it happening with the simple project? If it is, place the project on GitHub and share. Thanks.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kMOZTs5WoIw5CHf27GMSvSYxTM8r5Gsv

Comment: posted the answer. have a look at.

Comment: is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely related to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1881/_index.html) since you have a mixed language project.

Try setting Embedded Content Contains Swift Code to YES

Comment: In swift project this option not available.

Answer (score 0):

make the "*Always Embed Swift standard libraries*" from **NO** to **YES**.

Let me know if it works for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check all frameworks you add to your application. Probably one of them needs to be added to the 'Enbedded Binaries' section on the General page of the main target. For example, Zip.Framework.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working on a iOS project in a workspace with multiple other modules. The iOS app target had declared some of them but not all of them, as the app target didn't use all of them. The ones it didn't use were used by other modules in the workspace. Furthermore, every time I would run the app on simulators it would work as expected, but would fail each time when ran on a hardware device.

Lo and behold — thanks to [Pavel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124728/6744473) —, I discovered that the same "libraries" it was complaining about not being able to be found were the exact same libraries that happened to be not included within the the app target. So I added them despite the app module itself not utilizing them at all, and voila, working exactly as expected.