# XCode 9 failed to build : Dyld error message Image not found

Tags: cocoapods, xcode9, kvnprogress

On **XCode 9**, I'm not able to build my project, with this error :

```
KVNProgress Group/Users/xxx/Documents/project/Pods/KVNProgress/KVNProgress/Resources/KVNProgressView.xib
/Users/xxx/development/project/Pods/KVNProgress/KVNProgress/Resources/KVNProgressView.xib: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "/var/folders/kb/3qmqmk_569v9ggc23nnc5btm0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2018-02-16_10-30-34_345000".
```

Crash detail :

```
Process:               Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool [10066]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool
Identifier:            Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool
Version:               9.2 (13772)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ibtoold [10050]
Responsible:           Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool [10066]
User ID:               262
Date/Time:             2018-02-15 14:33:28.445 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G1114)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        C68970F4-1365-1C3A-554B-396EA6A954FC
Time Awake Since Boot: 1800 seconds
System Integrity Protection: enabled
Crashed Thread:        0
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks
Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/CoreAnalytics
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
Reason: image not found
```

I tried a lot of solutions from [Reason: no suitable image found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found) but I still have the problem.

**Important precision** : On my other mac, the project build correctly.
Before yesterday, project build on this mac...

I tried to delete and recreate all the Provisioning profile and Certificates, to delete XCode cash, remove project and recreate from git and install pod again, restart mac, clean derived data, but nothing works...

Other precision : I'm not able to build another project with KVNProgress lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Avast quarantined the file that was missing.
Restored the file and Xcode worked fine