# Xcode 10.2 can not successly load Auth0 framework with cocoapods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, auth0

I use Xcode 10.2 to `pod install` the Auth0 framework, but the build fails on the simulator on my company MacBook (by the way, it can build successfully on a real device). When I copy this project to my own MacBook, it builds successfully on both simulator and real device.

What I did:

1. Create a new project
2. `pod init` and add `pod 'Auth0', '~> 1.13'` to pod file
3. `pod install` and `import Auth0` in `AppDelegate.swift`
4. build

The error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Auth0.framework/Auth0
  Referenced from: /Users/jliu396/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E598229-351C-42E8-A64B-D7E3BFC24E04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/823447BC-672C-444C-B12A-7A8BA18B3E4A/Auth0FrameworkTest.app/Auth0FrameworkTest
  Reason: no suitable image found.
  Did find:
    /Users/jliu396/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E598229-351C-42E8-A64B-D7E3BFC24E04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/823447BC-672C-444C-B12A-7A8BA18B3E4A/Auth0FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/Auth0.framework/Auth0: mmap() errno=5 at address=0x10BD1B000, size=0x00084000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /Users/jliu396/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E598229-351C-42E8-A64B-D7E3BFC24E04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/823447BC-672C-444C-B12A-7A8BA18B3E4A/Auth0FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/Auth0.framework/Auth0
    /Users/jliu396/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E598229-351C-42E8-A64B-D7E3BFC24E04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/823447BC-672C-444C-B12A-7A8BA18B3E4A/Auth0FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/Auth0.framework/Auth0: mmap() errno=5 at address=0x10BE54000, size=0x00084000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /Users/jliu396/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E598229-351C-42E8-A64B-D7E3BFC24E04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/823447BC-672C-444C-B12A-7A8BA18B3E4A/Auth0FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/Auth0.framework/Auth0
    /Users/jliu396/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E598229-351C-42E8-A64B-D7E3BFC24E04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/823447BC-672C-444C-B12A-7A8BA18B3E4A/Auth0FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/Auth0.framework/Auth0: stat() failed with errno=5
    /Users/jliu396/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E598229-351C-42E8-A64B-D7E3BFC24E04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/823447BC-672C-444C-B12A-7A8BA18B3E4A/Auth0FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/Auth0.framework/Auth0: mmap() errno=5 at address=0x10BF8D000, size=0x00084000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /Users/jliu396/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E598229-351C-42E8-A64B-D7E3BFC24E04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/823447BC-672C-444C-B12A-7A8BA18B3E4A/Auth0FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/Auth0.framework/Auth0
    /Users/jliu396/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E598229-351C-42E8-A64B-D7E3BFC24E04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/823447BC-672C-444C-B12A-7A8BA18B3E4A/Auth0FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/Auth0.framework/Auth0: stat() failed with errno=5
```

The pod file is:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Auth0FrameworkTest' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Auth0', '~> 1.13'
# Pods for Auth0FrameworkTest

end
```

Comment: I try many solutions in stackoverflow, it do not work for me

Comment: Check whether your are running correct configuration in Xcode scheme editor.

Comment: Jiqing Liu can you please share your Podfile's content. Best

Comment: Update the pod file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason: no suitable image found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found) Please check answers under the shared question. Hope will fix your problem, best.