# Can't build project to physical device Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, build

I cant build my Xcode project to a physical device. Simulated devices are working perfectly. I installed every cocoapods library again and cleaned the project multiple times.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Segler
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFE145F7-D789-4DB8-A0DB-D8B533D08B5A/Segler.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScanner.framework/BarcodeScanner: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like your project.xcodeproj path is wrong or something, I found this on someone's question/answer and look like he got the same problem as you. Hope this helps you.

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found%5D)