# Xcode Swift App Error Importing Alamofire Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm trying to build Alamofire App on my Device (iPhone 7). But faced some troubles:

Please help fix that issue:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>
> Referenced from:
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/PFXAuth
>
> Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
> code signature invalid for
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
> stat() failed with errno=25
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
> code signature invalid for
> '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
> stat() failed with errno=1
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
> code signature invalid for
> '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B129CA-9E0A-41C4-BB8B-3328E36F7FE0/PFXAuth.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
> stat() failed with errno=1 (lldb)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reason: no suitable image found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found)

Comment: what version of swift and xcode you are using @Oleg

Comment: Swift 5 / Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504

Comment: In Xcode 11 you should prefer Swift Package Manager over CocoaPods

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps Adding Frameworks to Your Xcode Project
http://docs.onemobilesdk.aol.com/ios-ad-sdk/adding-frameworks-xcode.html

Answer (score 0):

add Alamofire.framework to Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on Xcode 11.3 and iOS 13.2 nothing worked for me. But It runs on simulators and on devices need  purchased Apple developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use Alamofire and Cocoapods inside my PFXAuth Project

fulfilled recommendations
http://docs.onemobilesdk.aol.com/ios-ad-sdk/adding-frameworks-xcode.html

but the imported framework Alamofire looks transparent (something wrong)

[image]

But the same error fixed %(

Commenting in **Podfile** row **use_frameworks!** helps !