# Problem executing some library in iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to run my application in a real iOS device, but it is giving me the next error that I have no idea what to do to solve:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libsndfile.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7366AC4C-A729-4AB4-A2F6-7ADB2FC71B5D/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7366AC4C-A729-4AB4-A2F6-7ADB2FC71B5D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libsndfile.1.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7366AC4C-A729-4AB4-A2F6-7ADB2FC71B5D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libsndfile.1.dylib'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7366AC4C-A729-4AB4-A2F6-7ADB2FC71B5D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libsndfile.1.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7366AC4C-A729-4AB4-A2F6-7ADB2FC71B5D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libsndfile.1.dylib'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7366AC4C-A729-4AB4-A2F6-7ADB2FC71B5D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libsndfile.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7366AC4C-A729-4AB4-A2F6-7ADB2FC71B5D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libsndfile.1.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7366AC4C-A729-4AB4-A2F6-7ADB2FC71B5D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libsndfile.1.dylib'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7366AC4C-A729-4AB4-A2F6-7ADB2FC71B5D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libsndfile.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

When I run my app in my own device, it works perfectly, but when I run it in any other device, the app doesn't even open, it just crashes and throws that error.

Comment: Did you "trust" this other device after connecting? Also are you on a paid developer account? Did you clean & rebuild app? Restart Xcode? _You know, the normal pre-checks before asking the question; the steps which you should have included in your question to make it easier_

Comment: Checkout this link. I think your problem similar with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found

Comment: I've done all of that and I'm still getting the error

Comment: Do you solve this error ? @EdwardPizzurro