# Swift UITableView works in simulator but i'm facing an error when i run it on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, fatal-error

This is my code creating a UITableView using storyboard hten i update my ViewController.swift file like this. Its working fine in when i run it in simulator, but i an facing an error at the time of i run it in my device

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewObject: UITableView!
var foodNames: [String] = ["Food1","Food2","Food3","Food4","Food5","Food6","Food7","Food8"];
var foodImages: [String] = ["image1", "image2", "image3","image4","image5","image6","image7","image8"];


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return foodNames.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")
    cell.textLabel.text = foodNames[indexPath.row]

    var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: foodImages[indexPath.row])!
    cell.imageView.image = image
    cell.imageView.sizeToFit()

    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

I am facing this error shown below
[image]

Comment: it's telling you in the logs that the device doesn't have the images you want to add. Try setting a breakpoint  after the image init and see if it is nil

Comment: possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: @YuviGr it is just load up to launch screen then it crash with the error what i an showing in the above attached image... thanq any way :-)

Comment: was viewDidLoad called?

Comment: no its not calling before that only the crash happens @YuviGr

Answer (score 0):

From your loge: `dylib library not loaded libSwiftCore.`

This means that you have issue with Frameworks(dynamic libraries).

Please check followin [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

I think you will find which is your case.
Hope this will help.