# Integrate Swift framework to objective-c application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to integrate swift framework with objective-c application.when i am running i am getting a crash

```
@objc public class EquipmentManager{

var sampleString : String = ""

@objc public init(str:String){
    self.sampleString = str
}

@objc public func returnString() ->NSString{
    return sampleString
}
}
```

I am trying to access this class
**dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/EquipmentManager.framework/EquipmentManager
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0A26433B-B169-48A7-A006-528D076FB8A9/ObjcTest.app/ObjcTest
  Reason: image not found**

Has anyone integrated objective-c application with swift framework?

Comment: i could access swift code within the same application. My problem is that i have created a swift framework and when i try to access it, I am getting a crash.

Comment: Than YOU should check this out : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Check out this also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This out:

There is an "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" flag in the Build Settings that needs to be set to YES. It is NO by default!

[image]

Reference: [TALAA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26949219/3859370)

Hope This Works!

Comment: thank you! just spent more time than I care to admit trying to figure out why a way for adding an embedded binary to an objective-c app wouldn't work even though it was working for swift apps... wish I had gotten here sooner!