# Cannot run swift project on phone. dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Tags: ios, swift

**1. File new project** . Single View Application , Objective C . Run . Runs on iphone

**2. File new project** . Single View Application, Swift . Run . Following error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3FB09C8-29C3-4389-9B3F-4F355FDF8EC8/Test.app/Test
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3FB09C8-29C3-4389-9B3F-4F355FDF8EC8/Test.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x001E3000, size=0x00168000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3FB09C8-29C3-4389-9B3F-4F355FDF8EC8/Test.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
```

**Environment** : `Xcode Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)`

Created new certificate and profile.Didn't help .

Comment: What OS is the phone running? UPDATE: nvm, you mention an iPhone 5 with iOS 8.3 in a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Go to keychain , and select the certificates .The certificates that have + sign (those are the ones that have always trust ) . Right click->Get Info-> expand the trust.Change them to "Use System Default" . This fixed for me . Do it to certificates that have + against them.

Answer (score 0):

Check that "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" is set to YES in your build settings.

This isn't to do with certificates.

If the above doesn't work, check that "Runpath Search Paths" is set to @executable_path/Frameworks

Comment: Checked "Runpath Search Paths" and it is set to @executable_path/Frameworks

Comment: What OS version is your iPhone running, and which iPhone model? Have you checked the related questions in the column to the right?

Comment: iPhone 5 (iOS 8.3) . Yes i did try the related questions . Especially this one  [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib. and to isolate the issue , went  to the file new project route  and could reproduce the same issue. I recently updated to Xcode 6.3.1 , but cannot say for sure this caused the problem . Objective C project works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your build settings, Set "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" to "YES"
and "Runpath Search Paths" to "@executable_path/Frameworks".

Comment: "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" is  "YES" and "Runpath Search Paths" is  "@executable_path/Frameworks". Yet does not work.