# Cocoapods issue with xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, cocoapods, alamofire

I am getting this error in Adhoc build , but in development mode it works just fine.

Dyld Error Message:

> Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>     Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA4702F0-6A4C-4EB6-99D0-255ABB6E3F57/Real Estate.app/Real Estate
>     Reason: image not found
>     Dyld Version: 353.12

Comment: What makes you think this is a CocoaPods issue? If you think it is, we need to see your Podfile.

Comment: Bcz i made a build without the pods and manually addying the frameworks it worked fine in the adhoc build .

Comment: target 'Real Estate' do


#pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.6'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'MMMaterialDesignSpinner'
pod 'SVPullToRefresh'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.9.2'
pod 'SwiftSpinner'
pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'

end

target 'Real EstateTests' do

end

Comment: possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Answer (score 2):

I spent several hours trying to fix this error, and I resolved only after create a brand new project with Xcode and use same pods. I just discovered that the in the Build Phases of target weren't last two sections:

[image: Missing phases]

They are defined as run scripts:

[image: Embed Pods Frameworks]

```
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-frameworks.sh"
```

And:

[image: Copy Pods Resources]

```
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-resources.sh"
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I also have the same issue.I tried every solutions above.But not working.Please help me to solve this.After adding framework in 'Copy Files Phase' and 'Linked libraries',in my project it shows the framework as in red color.So its telling like 'framework not found alamofire'