# Swift App Opens on Simulator But Not on Device

Tags: ios, swift, crash, dyld

I've been working on my iOS app for a while, and it builds and runs fine on the simulator, but when I try to run it on my device, a few things happen:

- The app launch screen appears
- The app crashes and my Xcode output is as follows:

  ```
  dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/18932CDB-57DA-4A87-B154-45B9F3CD01D0/Up & Down - Minimalistic, Beautiful Counter.app/Up & Down - Minimalistic, Beautiful Counter
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/18932CDB-57DA-4A87-B154-45B9F3CD01D0/Up & Down - Minimalistic, Beautiful Counter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x100110000, size=0x0015C000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/18932CDB-57DA-4A87-B154-45B9F3CD01D0/Up & Down - Minimalistic, Beautiful Counter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  (lldb)
  ```
- The following message also appears, with a few other similar errors:

  ```
  dyld`dyld_fatal_error:             Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1,subcode=0x1200f5088)
  ->  0x1200f5088 <+0>: brk    #0x3
  ```

So I don't waste your time, I would like to warn you that I have tried to clean and build, revoke and renew certificates, delete all breakpoints, and restart both Xcode and my iPhone.

Any ideas on how to make my app run on my device? Thanks!!!

Comment: Is your device the same model as the one you used in Simulator?

Comment: Yes it is, iPhone 6 Plus

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib

Comment: Seems to be the same, yet the solution (changing embedded content contains swift code to YES) doesn't work :/

Comment: I wonder if the ampersand has something to do with it.

Comment: Good point! How can I change the name easily throughout the app without ruining anything though?

Comment: Just make sure you are using Xcode 6.3.2 or later (to avoid the crashing bug). Then just double-click the project name and change it. The only thing that will break is your unit tests, but they are easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

My project has Cocapods and I'm using multiple schemes. Running pod update fixed something wrong that happened during a merge and now it runs fine.