# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SinchVerification.framework/SinchVerification

Tags: ios, sinch

I am trying to run Sinch Verification on iOS (Swift). I imported the project using Cocoapods. The project gets built correctly. But when I try to run it on simulator, it gives following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SinchVerification.framework/SinchVerification
  Referenced from: /Users/vishal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/31EA265F-D753-44E9-892C-59306E865073/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/192BC0E1-00DC-4178-A78D-C8C1CC568BD2/Myapp.app/Myapp
  Reason: image not found
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib), doesn't help. I can't even explicitly mention the framework file as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/101). I don't see Sinch in the targets section in build settings of Pods.

Answer (score 1):

The Sinch Swift frameworks are dynamic frameworks, so make sure that you’ve added the Sinch Swift framework bundles as Embedded Binaries. Further, In the Xcode target build settings, verify that the setting Runpath Search Paths is set to @executable_path/Frameworks.

[Documentation - Sinch Swift SDK](https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/ios/#swiftsdk)