# Swift MBProgressHUD worked all on simulator but not worked on actual device

Tags: ios, swift, mbprogresshud

I've used MBProgressHUD and it works well on simulator.
But it doesn't work on actual device.
This is what error occurs.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MBProgressHUD.framework/MBProgressHUD
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/95537F26-A2D4-4C5A-9F38-D5D294B3E96F/Bowden.app/Bowden
  Reason: image not found
```

Note that I don't use cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

Click on [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

This is causing because of lot more reasons. For me issue resolved with the below fix:

In my case the trust policy of my certificate in Keychain Access was **Always Trust**, changing it back to defaults solved the problem.

In order to open the certificate settings window double click the certificate in the Keychain Access list of certificates.

Comment: Please [edit] to quote the relevant information from the link, otherwise this answer is not useful if the link ever goes down.