# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib doesn't get solved by editting runpaths and Embedded Content Contains Swift Code

Tags: ios, xcode7.3, ios9.3

okay this websites have bunch of questions about the problem same as the title I post a new one cuz there's no post which help me..

I coded the whole project in xcode 7.3. And I'm trying to run it in both iOS 9.3.5 and 10.0.2.

Both prompted the error message below and it has been solved in 10.0.2, by downloading a certificate in https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ as advised in [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378756/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib). But 9.3.5 still doesn't work.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/69EF41F7-6DEA-49DC-A330-2356895A3267/이모저모.app/이모저모
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69EF41F7-6DEA-49DC-A330-2356895A3267/이모저모.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69EF41F7-6DEA-49DC-A330-2356895A3267/이모저모.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69EF41F7-6DEA-49DC-A330-2356895A3267/이모저모.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69EF41F7-6DEA-49DC-A330-2356895A3267/이모저모.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69EF41F7-6DEA-49DC-A330-2356895A3267/이모저모.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69EF41F7-6DEA-49DC-A330-2356895A3267/이모저모.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
```

What I first referenced is [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002836/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswift-stdlib-core-dylib). I set `Runpath search paths` as `@executable_path/frameworks`. In Xcode 8.0 there is no `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` so I just added `@executable_path/Frameworks` and it was ok, but in 7.3 it still doesn't work.

Any idea? None of the questions with the same topic does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: I had the same problem and this is what sorted it for me.  It was a problme with the certificates permissions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41401399/559760