# Crash when running app. Xcode 7 swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

When I run my app on my device the app builds then crashes. I'm using swift 2, and I'm running it on an iPhone 6. It worked before but when I tried to add a save option it started crashing. I removed all references to the save option but it still crashes. I can run the app on a simulator but not on a device. As I said I could run it on my phone yesterday. Here is the error I get:

```js
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath / libswiftCore.dylib
Referenced from: /var/mobile / Containers / Bundle / Application / 0ACE5D12 - 6145 - 4C43 - B829 - C103E7016489 / CmdCombinerNew.app / CmdCombinerNew
Reason: no suitable image found.Did find:
  /private/var / mobile / Containers / Bundle / Application / 0ACE5D12 - 6145 - 4C43 - B829 - C103E7016489 / CmdCombinerNew.app / Frameworks / libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno = 1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0ACE5D12-6145-4C43-B829-C103E7016489/CmdCombinerNew.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib' (lldb)
```

Here is the code I use:

```js
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CmdCombinerNew
//
//  Created by Mathew Anderson on 2/2/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mathew Anderson. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    
    //create the variables for the text views
    @IBOutlet var FirstBlock: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var SettingsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var SecondBlock: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var ClockingCommands: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var InitialCommands: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var generateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var OutputCommand: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //replace the text in first & second block with random numbers [0][1][2][3][4]
        let num1 = arc4random_uniform(15) + 1
        let num2 = arc4random_uniform(15) + 1
        OutputCommand.hidden = true;
        FirstBlock.text = "stained_hardened_clay " + String(num1)
        SecondBlock.text = "stained_glass " + String(num2)
        
        //Make things fancy!!!
        ClockingCommands.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        InitialCommands.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        OutputCommand.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        SettingsButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        generateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {x
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func popover(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showView", sender: self)
    }


    @IBAction func Generate(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        OutputCommand.text = ""
        //stop the user from editing
        ClockingCommands.endEditing(true)
        InitialCommands.endEditing(true)
        
        //turn the command string into an array
        var ClockingCommandsArr = ClockingCommands.text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        let InitialCommandsArr = InitialCommands.text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        
        //get count of commands
        var commandsCount = 0
        var dummy = 0
        
        
        for commands in ClockingCommandsArr {
            if(commands.characters.first == "*") {
                ClockingCommandsArr.removeAtIndex(dummy)
                dummy = dummy - 1
            }
            dummy = dummy + 1
        }
        
        //print initial non-repeated output text
        func initial(){
            if(ClockingCommandsArr[0].characters.first != "*") {
         OutputCommand.text = "/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:\"minecraft:redstone_block\",Time:1s,Passengers:[{id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"minecraft:activator_rail\",Time:1s},{id:\"MinecartCommandBlock\",Command:\"fill ~" + String(commandsCount + 2) + " ~1 ~1 ~2 ~-1 ~-1 " + SecondBlock.text! + " hollow\"}" + ",{id:\"MinecartCommandBlock\",Command:\"fill ~" + String(commandsCount + 2) + " ~ ~1 ~2 ~ ~-1 " + FirstBlock.text! + " hollow\"},{id:\"MinecartCommandBlock\",Command:setblock ~3 ~ ~ repeating_command_block 5 replace {Command:" + ClockingCommandsArr[0] + ",auto:1b,TrackOutput:0b}}"
            }else{
                ClockingCommandsArr.removeFirst();
                initial()
            }
        }
        initial()
        ClockingCommandsArr.removeFirst()
        
        //write each command into the Output
        var labelText = "";
        for command in InitialCommandsArr {
            let nulledCommand = command.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
            if(nulledCommand.characters.count > 0 && nulledCommand.characters.first != "*"){
                
                labelText += ",{id:\"MinecartCommandBlock\",Command:\(command) }}"
            }
        }
        
        for command in ClockingCommandsArr {
            if(command.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") != ""){
                if(command.characters.first != "*") {
            OutputCommand.text = OutputCommand.text + ",{id:\"MinecartCommandBlock\",Command:setblock ~" + String(dummy + 4) + " ~ ~ chain_command_block 5 replace {auto:1,TrackOutput0b,Command:" + command + "}}"
                }
            }
        }
        OutputCommand.hidden = false;
        
    }
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showView"{
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
            let controller = vc.popoverPresentationController
            if controller != nil{
                controller?.delegate = self
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .None
    }

}
```

I have tried removing/refreshing my developer profile. Did not work. I ran it on a simulator on the same device and it worked. I made sure my developer profile is verified on my phone, and also deleting the existing app on the phone does not work. I have also deleted the developer profile on my phone and reset it and it still crashes. The app is put on my phone an when I open it the app freezes and never gets past the opening screen. Does this mean it could be something wrong with my viewDidLoad() function? I tried to update xcode but there is not an update available. My phone is running iOS 9.2.1 and my simulator says 9.2 so could this be the problem? I don't remember ever updating my phone in the last month so idk.

Just found out about this device logs thing. Here is what was outputted:

```js
Incident Identifier: 0EB64729-68B2-4F5A-A20A-4CB29B36E12A
CrashReporter Key:   f6d773325288fbf35c24f7fd64cf50b66d87425b
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             CmdCombinerNew [206]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2D5EB2C-21FB-4CA2-9F7E-1F12FA21B671/CmdCombinerNew.app/CmdCombinerNew
Identifier:          com.Matt.CmdCombinerNew
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-02-26 10:46:33.33 -0600
Launch Time:         2016-02-26 10:46:33.33 -0600
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000120021088
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2D5EB2C-21FB-4CA2-9F7E-1F12FA21B671/CmdCombinerNew.app/CmdCombinerNew
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2D5EB2C-21FB-4CA2-9F7E-1F12FA21B671/CmdCombinerNew.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2D5EB2C-21FB-4CA2-9F7E-1F12FA21B671/CmdCombinerNew.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
  Dyld Version: 370.6

Binary Images:
0x1000e4000 - 0x1000f3fff CmdCombinerNew arm64  <816d2190e79537ccb5b08fd7e3190c6b> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2D5EB2C-21FB-4CA2-9F7E-1F12FA21B671/CmdCombinerNew.app/CmdCombinerNew
0x120020000 - 0x12004ffff dyld arm64  <9e98992ceed735e2ac4784cb28efe7c1> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Hope all this info helps :D.

Comment: (Please use more detailed titles.) Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib

Comment: Check out this Stackoverflow post. Maybe it could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib

Comment: Did you delete the one from yesterday off of your device before trying the new version?

Comment: I added more info at the bottom. I tried to update xcode but there is not an update available. My phone is running iOS 9.2.1 and my simulator says 9.2 so could this be the problem? I don't remember ever updating my phone in the last month so idk.

Comment: Just tried to run the app just to make sure. And it completely broke my phone. I could not turn it on and had to hard reset it for it to turn on.

Comment: Bump... still trying to figure this out. Can't repost because It will get taken down.