# Dyld Library Not Loaded Error on Release Build

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I have a project that uses SimulatorStatusMagic in the Debug configuration only. So my Podfile has the following line:

```
pod 'SimulatorStatusMagic', :configurations => ['Debug']
```

The app works fine in Simulator, but when I compile for my device or upload to iTunes, I get the following error:

> Dyld Message: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/SimulatorStatusMagic.framework/SimulatorStatusMagic
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1E47674A-D9AB-4390-B365-85C1D9035624/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: None of the existing CocoaPods "Dyld Library Not Loaded" answers on Stack Overflow helped you?

Comment: No, they didn't. Look how crazy the answers are! So many different problems with similar error messages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. In AppDelegate.swift, I have the following code:

```
    if (Helper.isUITest) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        SDStatusBarManager.sharedInstance().enableOverrides()
    }
```

Even though Helper.isUITest always returns `false` for Release builds, the compiler doesn't know that and still emits the metadata/code to dynamically load the SimulatorStatusMagic framework.

Wrapping the above code in `#if DEBUG` fixed the issue.

```
    #if DEBUG
    if (Helper.isUITest) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        SDStatusBarManager.sharedInstance().enableOverrides()
    }
    #endif
```