# libSwiftCore.dylib image not found error on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator, breakpoints

i'm trying to create a basic app with swift. When i test it in the simulator it works but when i try to test it on my iPhone i get an error:

```
dyld`_dyld_start:
0x1200c9000 <+0>:   mov    x28, sp
0x1200c9004 <+4>:   and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
0x1200c9008 <+8>:   movz   x0, #0
0x1200c900c <+12>:  movz   x1, #0
0x1200c9010 <+16>:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-16]!
0x1200c9014 <+20>:  mov    x29, sp
0x1200c9018 <+24>:  sub    sp, sp, #16               ; =16 
0x1200c901c <+28>:  ldr    x0, [x28]
0x1200c9020 <+32>:  ldr    x1, [x28, #8]
0x1200c9024 <+36>:  add    x2, x28, #16              ; =16 
0x1200c9028 <+40>:  adrp   x4, -1
0x1200c902c <+44>:  add    x4, x4, #0                ; =0 
0x1200c9030 <+48>:  adrp   x3, 48
0x1200c9034 <+52>:  ldr    x3, [x3, #3320]
0x1200c9038 <+56>:  sub    x3, x4, x3
0x1200c903c <+60>:  mov    x5, sp
0x1200c9040 <+64>:  bl     0x1200c908c               ; dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)
0x1200c9044 <+68>:  mov    x16, x0 //THE ERROR IS IN THIS LINE
0x1200c9048 <+72>:  ldr    x1, [sp]
0x1200c904c <+76>:  cmp    x1, #0                    ; =0 
0x1200c9050 <+80>:  b.ne   0x1200c905c               ; <+92>
0x1200c9054 <+84>:  add    sp, x28, #8               ; =8 
0x1200c9058 <+88>:  br     x16
0x1200c905c <+92>:  mov    x30, x1
0x1200c9060 <+96>:  ldr    x0, [x28, #8]
0x1200c9064 <+100>: add    x1, x28, #16              ; =16 
0x1200c9068 <+104>: add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
0x1200c906c <+108>: add    x2, x2, #8                ; =8 
0x1200c9070 <+112>: mov    x3, x2
0x1200c9074 <+116>: ldr    x4, [x3]
0x1200c9078 <+120>: add    x3, x3, #8                ; =8 
0x1200c907c <+124>: cmp    x4, #0                    ; =0 
0x1200c9080 <+128>: b.ne   0x1200c9074               ; <+116>
0x1200c9084 <+132>: br     x16
```

When i try to reinstall the app i get different errors but similar, here's some of them:

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1200c9088)
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1200f5088)
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1200e5088)
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x120091088)
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x120059088)
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1200b5088)
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x120099088)
```

I've already searched on internet and it seems a popular error but i didn't find a solution that worked for me. I tried cleaning the project, checking breakpoints, deleting DerivedData but no one of these tasks resolved my error.
This is my error screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIjGV.png
Someone can help me?

Comment: The important part is the bit in the console: "libSwiftCore.dylib -- image not found"  Did you search for that (I see a lot of helpful advice). https://www.google.com/search?q=libSwiftCore.dylib+image+not+found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it!
If someone has my problem, this solution worked for me:

-1 Go to keychain access select "System" in "Kechains" and "All Items" in "Category"
There will be a certificate with name "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority". Delete that certificate if it's expired or is showing as signed by unauthorized identifier

-2 Goto https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ and download "Worldwide Developer Relations - G2 Certificate" under "Apple Intermediate Certificates"

-3 Install the certificate

-4 Clean, Build and run.