# new created swift project is crashing in device

Tags: xcode, swift, crash

I created a new swift project in xcode and run the app in device. I am getting below crash :

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib   Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/07AB485A-D1E4-4602-BA12-28861A9CE4A3/VC.app/VC   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:  /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/07AB485A-D1E4-4602-BA12-28861A9CE4A3/VC.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/07AB485A-D1E4-4602-BA12-28861A9CE4A3/VC.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: Not resolved using that post answers

Answer (score 0):

do following ::

> > Add the following line to Runpath Search Paths of your target.

paste this

> @executable_path/Frameworks

in yourApp_target -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Runpath Search Paths

Comment: Do the same for test targets

Comment: Same Result Mr. JAck Thanks!

Comment: i think something corrupt in system lib need to reset system.

Comment: Try to remove podfile and and create and install pods again also build required frameworks. This is only heppens because of un mapping  library to the program

Comment: i create a simple project of swift it's crashing and objective c project working fine

Comment: no pod file included in project even no framework used

Comment: have you deleted derived data??