# dyld`dyld_fatal_error: 0x120021088 <+0>: brk #0x3

Tags: swift

I am creating a "helloWorld" iOS app in swift. App is working fine in simulator. But when I install the app on device "iPad" it is giving error

> "dyld`dyld_fatal_error: 0x12006d088 <+0>: brk    #0x3
>   Thread1:EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x12006d088)

**Error Description:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/2FB154F4-4FE8-484C-AE3D-425449EA3630/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2FB154F4-4FE8-484C-AE3D-425449EA3630/HelloWorld.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2FB154F4-4FE8-484C-AE3D-425449EA3630/HelloWorld.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
```

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib