# Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Tags: ios, swift

I use Xcode 8.1 and after adding CocoaPods and Objective-C files to my workspace I can't run app on my device. This is error from console:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EAB92875-7A43-4DA0-8CB8-1C95A3AAF8EE/See My Progress.app/See My Progress
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EAB92875-7A43-4DA0-8CB8-1C95A3AAF8EE/See My Progress.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EAB92875-7A43-4DA0-8CB8-1C95A3AAF8EE/See My Progress.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

I have tried recreating signing certificate, enabling/disabling Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries, clearing and reinstalling Xcode. Nothing helped

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution helped me in a few minutes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41401399/559760