# App crashing on launch with "dyld: Library not loaded" error in iOS 11, but was running fine in iOS 10.3.2 and Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, ios11, xcode9-beta

On updating the Xcode to beta 9 and running the application in the iOS 11 version I am getting the crash with the following error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>     Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFB7F820-B03B-4200-8813-3C3E01032A2F/TIMAutoConnect.app/Frameworks/UTCTIMAccess.framework/UTCTIMAccess
>     Reason: image not found

Previously I fixed the error by setting "Always Embed Swift Binaries" to YES in build settings.

Note: The application uses a custom framework written in Swift and the application code is in Objective C.

Comment: clean the project rebuild i hope so working fine also removed derived data

Comment: I have the exact problem as you. Cleaning/deleting derived data does not help like in previous Xcode versions.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project, and deleting the derived data from the following path:

****(~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/)****

fixed it for me...

Have you missed any framework to import.Check first/ error in IBOutlet connection/missing any image.

Check the following link. It can help you.

**[dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)**

Answer (score 0):

Your custom framework (UTCTIMAccess.framework) was likely built with an older version of Swift. Rebuild it with Swift4 and it should work.