# Xamarin Embedded content contains Swift code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I have created binding library successfully, it is initialized properly in Xamarin.iOS app, but at specific point, the app is crashing.
I tried to implement the same on XCode, it is crashing also, but the issue has been fixed by enabling the option `Embedded content contains Swift Code` = `true` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26949219/5746504).

**So How to enable same option in Xamarin?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of Swift frameworks and inclusion of the Swift support libs are not officially supported in the Xamarin build process and thus you have to manually bundle the relevant Swift support libraries into your `Xamarin.iOS` app.

**Note:** You have to make sure you include the correct version of those libraries.

User `Flash3001` on Github has created Nugets/packages for the Swift frameworks

- https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.Swift3.Support

#### Swift 4

Libraries:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Accelerate/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.ARKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.AssetsLibrary/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.AVFoundation/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.CallKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.CloudKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Contacts/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Core/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.CoreAudio/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.CoreData/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.CoreFoundation/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.CoreGraphics/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.CoreImage/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.CoreLocation/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.CoreMedia/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Darwin/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Dispatch/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Foundation/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.GameplayKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.GLKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.HomeKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.MapKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.MediaPlayer/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Metal/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.MetalKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.ModelIO/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Intents/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.ObjectiveC/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.OS/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Photos/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.QuartzCore/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.RemoteMirror/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.SceneKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.SIMD/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.SpriteKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.SwiftOnoneSupport/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.UIKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.Vision/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.WatchKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.XCTest/

#### Swift 3

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.AssetsLibrary/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.AVFoundation/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.CallKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.CloudKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.Contacts/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.Core/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.CoreAudio/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.CoreData/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.CoreGraphics/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.CoreImage/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.CoreLocation/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.CoreMedia/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.Darwin/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.Dispatch/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.Foundation/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.GameplayKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.GLKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.HomeKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.MapKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.Intents/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.ObjectiveC/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.OS/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.Photos/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.QuartzCore/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.RemoteMirror/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.SceneKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.SIMD/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.SpriteKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.SwiftOnoneSupport/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.UIKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.WatchKit/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift3.XCTest/

Comment: Thanks, where shall I add the required nugets? in Xamarin.iOS or in Binding Library project?

Comment: @MoamenNaanou In the `Xamarin.iOS` **application** project

Comment: After adding the required library, the app is crashing after installation on iPhone simulator immediately, and error on VS is only `The app has been terminated.`

Comment: @MoamenNaanou Have you tried on a physical device? I know that those libraries include the simulator versions as Apple has *separate* fat libraries for `armv7 armv7s arm64` and `i386 x86_64`. Otherwise I would post a new issue on that GitHub project...

Comment: Yeah Actually I tried both physical device and simulator. It is weird, because before adding the nuget libs, the app was working properly but on specific point it was crashing, now after adding the nuget libs, it is crashing immediately after initialization, and the most weird point that I tried to add the binding library + nuget libs in empty project, and it is initialized properly!

Comment: @MoamenNaanou `I tried to add the binding library + nuget libs in empty project, and it is initialized properly` No sure I understand... so your Swift framework is working in a new application project but not your original one?