# Can't build/load my app on an iphone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Created a simple app which prototype works on virtual SE and 8 plus however i can not build it on a physical iPhone8Plus ..i only get while screen, and this error message

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
0x104d8af14 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
0x104d8af18 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x104d8af1c <+8>:  b.lo   0x104d8af34               ; <+32>
0x104d8af20 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
0x104d8af24 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
0x104d8af28 <+20>: bl     0x104d8a5b0               ; cerror_nocancel
0x104d8af2c <+24>: mov    sp, x29
0x104d8af30 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
0x104d8af34 <+32>: ret
```

one one with the arrow is displayed red and i also get this in my debug

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
```

Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/73798F76-73E4-49C3-      B36F-7DD3F61F8A4F/BodyBeats.app/BodyBeats
    Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/73798F76-73E4-49C3-B36F-7DD3F61F8A4F/BodyBeats.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/73798F76-73E4-49C3-B36F-7DD3F61F8A4F/BodyBeats.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

(lldb)

i tried restarting both iPhone and my MacBook...any ideas?

Comment: have tried with deleting cache data Xcode

Comment: What code signing configuration have you set up?

Comment: The ios version is the same on device and simulator ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)