# App crashes despite of build succeeds Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running my iOS app in Xcode but during running this error is being poped. I don't know what does that mean, despite of build succeeds. I have deployment target 10.3 and base SDK is latest(ios 11.0)

I am getting error at this line:

```
->  0x2871dc <+24>: pop    {r4, r5, r6, r8}
```

**Here is what I found in console:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DDD0BAF-C6B9-4EB6-B3FE-723EE3DFBE7F/IAuditor.app/IAuditor

Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DDD0BAF-C6B9-4EB6-B3FE-723EE3DFBE7F/IAuditor.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DDD0BAF-C6B9-4EB6-B3FE-723EE3DFBE7F/IAuditor.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

(lldb)
```

**Here is what appears in Xcode after running my app**

[image]

Comment: Enable zombie to get a better crash report. Go to Edit Schema -> Run -> Diagnostics -> zombie Objects.

Comment: Try [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26024100/2710486) ?

Comment: @zcui93 enabled building............

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your library/framework links under "**Embed Frameworks**" under Build phases on your app target, as your project is using Swift code.

So add the framework mentioned in your log to Embed Frameworks

Comment: is it fixed now or u still facing the issue?