# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AnyFormatKit.framework/AnyFormatKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Edit: Couldn't solve it with the answers in the duplicate question and the other answers posted here, but ended up copying the source code of the library directly in my project. This way, it works.

I'm having the following runtime error when trying to run my app with AnyFormatKit library:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AnyFormatKit.framework/AnyFormatKit
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/recruta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1DA80144-E533-42D4-AD37-330F4DC051C0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E1D7058C-7D21-47F5-B513-180EC649B14D/IPS.app/IPS
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Users/recruta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1DA80144-E533-42D4-AD37-330F4DC051C0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E1D7058C-7D21-47F5-B513-180EC649B14D/IPS.app/Frameworks/AnyFormatKit.framework/AnyFormatKit:
>   required code signature missing for
>   '/Users/recruta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1DA80144-E533-42D4-AD37-330F4DC051C0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E1D7058C-7D21-47F5-B513-180EC649B14D/IPS.app/Frameworks/AnyFormatKit.framework/AnyFormatKit'
>
> /Users/recruta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1DA80144-E533-42D4-AD37-330F4DC051C0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E1D7058C-7D21-47F5-B513-180EC649B14D/IPS.app/Frameworks/AnyFormatKit.framework/AnyFormatKit:
>   required code signature missing for
>   '/Users/recruta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1DA80144-E533-42D4-AD37-330F4DC051C0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E1D7058C-7D21-47F5-B513-180EC649B14D/IPS.app/Frameworks/AnyFormatKit.framework/AnyFormatKit'
>
> /Users/recruta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1DA80144-E533-42D4-AD37-330F4DC051C0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E1D7058C-7D21-47F5-B513-180EC649B14D/IPS.app/Frameworks/AnyFormatKit.framework/AnyFormatKit:
>   required code signature missing for
>   '/Users/recruta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1DA80144-E533-42D4-AD37-330F4DC051C0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E1D7058C-7D21-47F5-B513-180EC649B14D/IPS.app/Frameworks/AnyFormatKit.framework/AnyFormatKit'

I can't seem to resolve this. Any ideas what might be causing this problem?

Comment: you use pods.....

Comment: @Sh_Khan yes, I'm using pods to install it. Is it a pods problem then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Answer (score 0):

See this attached video [Demo](http://recordit.co/MHaI1NxJcK)

After install pods quite xcode and open from .xworkSpace , run with me

[image]

Comment: I tried creating a new project like you did, but the error persisted. Thanks for your effort in answering!

Comment: try do download the examples and from the libraries github of the framework,it works without errors