# Can't find my segmentation fault in my malloc shared library

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries, mmap

I recoded malloc free and realloc in c using mmap and munmap. I compiled them as a shared library .so file.

Here is a simple test:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char *addr;
    i = 0;
    while (i < 1024)
    {
        addr = (char*)malloc(1024);
        addr[0] = 42;
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Here is a run.sh that must replace the stdlib by my shared library:

```
#/bin/sh
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="libft_malloc.so"
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
$@
```

The problem is that when i am compiling directly the test file with my shared library and replacing the header in it, it is working well:

```
-> gcc test1.c libft_malloc.so
-> ./a.out
-> no error
```

But when i am running it with the run.sh that should just replace the official malloc library by my libft_malloc.so file, i am getting a segfault:

```
-> gcc test1.c
-> ./run.sh ./a.out
-> ./run.sh: line 5: 73502 Segmentation fault: 11  $@
```

I know the error is in my code and not in the run.sh or in the test.c because they are the officials files i must use to test my library in my school and those files are working well on other malloc repositories, but i can't find what can be the problem.

Here is my repository: https://github.com/Shirakawa42/malloc.git

I tried debugged by placing write() everywhere but the segfault don't seems to be in the malloc, so i'm lost.

edit:
It also segfault if we run a test without any malloc, but just by loading my library:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while (i < 1024)
    {
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

-> gcc test1.c
-> ./run.sh ./a.out
-> ./run.sh: line 5: 74764 Segmentation fault: 11  $@
```

edit 2:
Compiling with flag fsanitize=address repair the segfault, but it's absolutely not optimal

edit 3:
Setting the 2 first export manually in shell tell me:

```
dyld: warning: could not load inserted library 'libft_malloc.so' into library validated process because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    libft_malloc.so: code signing blocked mmap() of 'libft_malloc.so'
```

and after setting the third export all my actions make me segfault, like ls and vim, cd made me abort

Comment: "I tried debugged by placing write() everywhere" Tried running it in gdb?

Comment: i have not tried gdb i am actually trying but it's my first time

Comment: looks i can't use gdb has ./run.sh ./test is not recognized as an executable

Comment: just run ./test directly - set your environment variables in your shell so you don't need to use the run.sh wrapper.

Comment: What is the environment? MacOS, Xcode? Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dyld: warning: could not load inserted library 'libft_malloc.so' into library validated process because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    libft_malloc.so: code signing blocked mmap() of 'libft_malloc.so'
```

This error append when there are a segfault in your malloc or free, repairing free made it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it in gdb. First build your code with debug options:

```
gcc -g -O0
```

Above options should be used for both your lib and test program. Then you can try running you program in gdb:

```
gdb a.out
(gdb) r <arguments to a.out>
(gdb) bt     <-- when it crashes
```

Linux loads you program in the memory and calls the entry point `main`. Startup code that compiler adds for the platform may have calls to `malloc`. Hence, the crash without `malloc` in your test code.

Comment: i edited my question, the segfault appear when loading the library so i can't test gdb like that