# How to RUN a command line tool project in Xcode10.2

Tags: xcode, dyld, xcode10.2

I created a command line tool project in Xcode10.2.
I can build but can't run the project.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname etc...}/Build/Products/Debug/{Project name}
  Reason: image not found
```

what should I do?

I have already done following method but I couldn't solve this problem.
[dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: Whats the development language?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by updating my Mac, I hope this will help you.