# How to fix error when debugging Xamarin IOS App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have VS paired with a MAC build host and a device connected to the mac.

When i try to debug the app, the build succeed but the app doesn't launch.

**Error:**

> Launch failed. The app 'XXXXXXXXX.iOS' could not be launched on
>   'iPhone de teste'. Error: error HE0003: Could not load the framework
>   'libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib' (path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib):
>   not found

Comment: Maybe this answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: I have already tried that answers, but did not succeed!

Comment: Can you try add `Xamarin.Swift4.CoreFoundation`  nuget package in your project and change the link behavior when you debug?