# How to fix "Library not loaded... Reason: image not found" in Xcode Console Dev?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am learning Swift and when I jus write print("Hello World !"), I get an error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib ... Reason: image
>   not found

I already searched some answers but every time, the problem was about a `framework`, but I don't use any `framework`

I can't do anything if I can't print some text...

Comment: What is your Xcode version? And did you try to create another project?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Xcode, so 10.2. I am also using Xcode on virtual macOS 10.4.3 on VMware. I created more than 2 projects to check if it works better on another one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib Please  check this

Comment: If you are really running macOS 10.4.3, you're using a version that's 10 years out of date. If you're running 10.14.3, you may be juuuust a bit out of date. Are you able to try either (a) Xcode 10.1 with macOS 10.14.3 or (b) Xcode 10.2 with macOS 10.14.4? While most times Apple has no compatibility issues like what you are seeing, maybe this time there is something.

Comment: NOTES: (1) They released Xcode 10.2 and macOS 10.14.4 on the same day and most times I try to keep everything in sync. (2) One thing they released with Xcode 10.2 is Swift 5. What version of **Swift** is your project? (Swift 5 runtime is now part of the OS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I just upgraded macOS 10.4.3 to 10.4.4. Now there is no error. Thanks for your help