# "Library not loaded - no suitable image found" Error

Tags: ios, swift

Everything was working fine on both simulator and on real device however now when I try to run my app on my actual device I get a thread 1 error saying:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/EmptyDataSet_Swift.framework/EmptyDataSet_Swift
>
> Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EEAF155F-FE7F-491F-87DB-0693F9475F5B/SuperBeans.app/SuperBeans
>
> Reason: no suitable image found.

I have tried many solutions however to no avail. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What solutions have you tried.

Comment: cleaning the project, removing/reinstalling certificates, insuring always embed swift standard librarys is set to Yes, rebooting. It also says in the error, Did find:
 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/418C0483-AB62-446D-A710-FB39C01C6CCF/SuperBeans.app/Frameworks/EmptyDataSet_Swift.framework/EmptyDataSet_Swift: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/418C0483-AB62-446D-A710-FB39C01C6CCF/SuperBeans.app/Frameworks/EmptyDataSet_Swift.framework/EmptyDataSet_Swift'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: ive tried but nothing is making a difference. ive tried redownloading certificates etc

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid

Comment: There seems to be some kind of bug in latest iOS with regards to free dev accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on iOS 13.3.1 with xcode 11

Comment **use_frameworks!** in your **Podfile** and run **pod install**