# 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found with Cordova & Ionic 4

Tags: angular, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to integrate a login with Facebook into my application but this error has me desperate. I have tried all the solutions that are proposed in other discussions but for the moment I could not solve it.
My versions are as follows:

```
cordova --version 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
ionic --version 5.4.15
cordova-ios: 5.1.1
@ionic/angular: 4.11.10
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';

....

providers: [
    Facebook,
.....
]
.....
```

**login.page.ts**

```
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';

constructor( private fb: Facebook)  { }

async loginFacebook( ) {
    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(async (res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
```

When I execute the following command I get the error:

*ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"*

> /Users/PedroMadrigal/Desktop/escondite/platforms/ios/Escondite/Plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/FacebookConnectPlugin.h:13:9: fatal error: 
>         'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found
>
> ## import FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h
>
> 1 error generated.
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following versions work well for me:

- "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.15.1"
- "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^6.2.0"

If you are using different versions in your app, try using these versions. First, remove the current plugin by running the following commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook

npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/facebook
```

Then, reinstall the plugin with the stated versions using:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4@6.2.0 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="your app"

npm install --save @ionic-native/facebook@5.15.1
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to eliminate pods. Thanks @HaniBhat

Comment: Hello, I have the same error, can you explain what you did for "I also had to eliminate pods" ? thanks

Comment: Hello. I did these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I spent a lot of time searching for a solution and I couldn't find it. So after a big research I found that I was missing the cocoapods (https://cocoapods.org), so I installed the cocoapods and then I tried to install the plugin several times until the Cordova-plugin-facebook was installed successfully. It might sound a little bit wear but trust me, it worked for me. I hope this could help you.