# dyld: Library not loaded(abort_with_payload) After update to 10.15.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, build

After update my macOS to 10.15.3 its stop run on my device

I try to update the libraries but still not working while it works fine on the simulator.

my Xcode version 11.3.1
my iOS version 13.3.1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post the complete error text, not an image.  The "code signature invalid for..." looks like the culprit.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid) is possibly related.

Comment: I'll check it thank you

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error. I think the problem is iOS 13.3.1. If you have an older device that is not updated to that version, I think you should use it and see if the app works on that device. It worked for me. You could also try and restore your iPhone to older versions of iOS. I'm pretty sure that iOS 13.3 and below will work fine, it's just iOS 13.3.1.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yab you right i back to the old version and its work and I hope the new update will fix that issue