# How to fix error "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm" when simulating app from physical device in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, realm, simulator

I can run the app just fine when I run it through a virtual Simulator, but when I attempt to run it via physical device, I'm seeing this error and the app doesn't run. How can I fix this issue?

This is the error that I'm receiving...

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/SectionRowsTutorial
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7B8B38D1-FE2D-4C17-9FD0-17246FB751DF/SectionRowsTutorial.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Comment: to run on device you need team, certs, etc. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running_your_app_in_the_simulator_or_on_a_device

Comment: I got all those things setup. It used to work find until just recently.

Comment: Embed the framework. Don't just link against it.

Comment: This issue could be a number of things. Try re-logging into your account in the XCode preferences. While you're there, check Manage Certificates. Also, log into your developer account on the apple developer site and ensure you've agreed to the terms and conditions. Also check your Team and Signing Certificate is correct in your app. Lastly, with iOS 13.3, the behavior of the free develop accounts changed (for security) and it no longer allows  embedded frameworks to be used. If you're using cocoapods, change `use_frameworks!` to `use_modular_headers!`. However, that may break other podfiles.

Comment: @Jay I appreciate the help. I tried everything that you've suggested, but I'm still seeing that same error.

Comment: free....for now

Comment: This seesm to be an issue related to iOS 13.3.1 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid

Comment: Sure looks like it. Appreciate the help.