# dyld: Library not loaded error in Swift - IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

My app has been building and testing successfully on my iPhone since I began development.

It just started failing to build within the simulator; a Clean Build Folder fixed the simulator, but now when building on my phone I get:

> ```
>   Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/89F8B333-855C-4DE8-8A6A-E2472EF176DA/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/89F8B333-855C-4DE8-8A6A-E2472EF176DA/MyApp.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManagerSwift.framework/IQKeyboardManagerSwift: 
>     code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/89F8B333-855C-4DE8-8A6A-E2472EF176DA/MyApp.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManagerSwift.framework/IQKeyboardManagerSwift'`
> ```

This is out of the blue; I've not done anything to the keyboard library, I've not added any new libraries.

Comment: This seems to be an issues related to iOS 13.3.1 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid

Answer (score 1):

From @Paul11100 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid)

1. Open the podfile
2. Comment out use_frameworks!
3. Add use_modular_headers!
4. In Terminal, do a pod update -> pod install
5. In Xcode, Clean (Command-Shift-K) -> Build and Run.

Source: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051

Answer (score 0):

This might have happened if your certificates are revoked.

You may try to clean the project and clean the derived data by doing CMD-Shift-K and `XCode -> Preferences -> Locations -> goto your Derived Data folder` and delete your project files.

If nothing works try to use terminal with the below command

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
```