# iOS 13.3.1 error "dyld: Library not loaded:...Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:..." application crash [swift][xcode]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dyld

After updating your phone to iOS 13.3.1 the application stopped running! Start and crash and error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/AppName
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/268CB30E-7E71-473D-BFC4-A548A20D6F00/AppName.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: stat() failed with errno=1
```

In a simulator (iOS 13.3) and on another phone with iOS 13.3, the application runs

Maybe someone who's faced a problem like this, please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running iOS apps causes runtime error for frameworks "code signature invalid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid)

Comment: This is an issue with iOS 13.3.1. All dynamic frameworks being compiled to the newest release of iOS 13.3.1 are experiencing this issue when running on a personal provisioning profile/developer account.

You can:

Use a non-Personal Team provisioning profile (paid developer account).
Run on the 13.3.1 simulator.
Test on a real iOS device running 13.3 or lower.
Hopefully this issue will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's something with a dynamic framework. If you are using CocoaPods, comment the use_frameworks! line in the Podfile, do a pod update, pod install, clean and run.