# Running iOS app on device causes runtime error

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

When I try to run my app on an iPhone I get the following error. Running on a simulator is fine.

```
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4108D01F-FE3D-49AD-BDAA-1D020A41DB65/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4108D01F-FE3D-49AD-BDAA-1D020A41DB65/MyApp.app/Frameworks/ExampleSDK.framework/ExampleSDK: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4108D01F-FE3D-49AD-BDAA-1D020A41DB65/SDKDevApp.app/Frameworks/ExampleSDK.framework/ExampleSDK'
```

This is basically worked yesterday, and suddenly it doesn't today.

I already tried out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid) and found this [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115451) but the solution exposed there don't work for me.

I tried out using both Cocoapods and just simply adding the framework to my project.

Comment: Do you have the image it is referring to added to your assets?

Comment: `no suitable image found` does not mean that an image/picture asset is missing. It means the the whole binary is not found. Try to clean the Project and delete the Derived Data directory.

Comment: @seeya I already tried that several times, also restarted Xcode and all the shabang but nothing.

Comment: did you try to remove the pod framework and install again? even try to clean, close and restart the machine itself.

Comment: yup, all of that, I even deleted the provisioning profiles from the phone and reinstalled them.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that it only reproduces on iPhones with iOS 13.3.1
I don't know if it's because of that, but since everything the you guys suggested din't work I will close this and treat it as an iOS 13.3.1 bug until otherwise proven.