# After edit unix binary file in Mac, How can I pass the code signature check?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, unix, code-signing, codesign

1. for some reason.I edit a little code(just replace a link address) in `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/83.0.4103.61/Google Chrome Framework`.(use the Hex Fiend editor)
2. After doing that.When I reopen Google Chrome.I got the error message from the system:

```
EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
```

3. I know to edit the third-party application maybe not a good practice. But if i want to do like this.Can you give me some tips.Is it possible to close the code signature check on my mac?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run an iOS app that causes runtime error for frameworks "code signature invalid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/how-to-run-an-ios-app-that-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-i)

Comment: @DigvijayS no! If you don't make sure.Please don't suggest another question.Leave my question here will be more helpful.Thanks.