# Swift 5 My error while install to test Real Device

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift5

I use cocoapods run and testing 2 moths but just have problem like this.

```rb
pod 'SwiftyRSA'
pod 'Hover'
pod 'SwiftVideoBackground'
```

Now I can't not install with real device. How can I fix this error?

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Hover.framework/Hover
>    Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C92CEFBB-DC69-4CFA-B32E-B3A14F69CF0A/7FUN7.app/7FUN7
>
> Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C92CEFBB-DC69-4CFA-B32E-B3A14F69CF0A/7FUN7.app/Frameworks/Hover.framework/Hover: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C92CEFBB-DC69-4CFA-B32E-B3A14F69CF0A/7FUN7.app/Frameworks/Hover.framework/Hover'

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your derivedData and run project and also update pod file by terminal. or may be below link help you [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: do you have sample?

Comment: and where derivedData place?

Comment: You can check here how to delete derivedData   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8

Comment: I deleted derivedData but still problem

Comment: Did you update pod file by terminal or check your provisioning profile is valid or set development profile only in Xcode for debugging.